# What is the function organized on reaching 60 years of age?

Tags: scripture

Long time ago I read that reaching the age of 60 years means one has completed 50% of their lifespan and to mark this occasion, a function is organized to celebrate it.

Of course, not everyone lives for 120 years but generally, a function is organized for everyone who touches 60 years. I vaguely remember from that article that the basis of this function is found in scripture.

What is it and where is it mentioned?

Comment: It is called Shashthi poorthi.

Comment: Its Shasti poorthi. 60th marriage function!

Comment: @LazyLubber Thanks for the term, if you have references from scripture(s), please post an answer.

Comment: @AkshayS Thanks, I read about it but it isn't related to marriage function! Wikipedia says planets are in same position at attaining 60 years of age when they were at the birth of individual.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yes its actually not a marriage function but it is celebrated as 60th marriage!!!